# how to go from swing to android for view updating?

Tags: java, android, swing, model-view-controller, android-custom-view

New to android programming but what I am trying to do is I have this piece of code that I wrote back some time using Swing. I looking to be able to convert this to do the same in android. the interface code and class code is below:

The interface:

```
public interface CellView {
  void update();
  JComponent getComponent();
}
```

The class

```
public class ComponentCellView implements CellView {
  private JComponent component;
  public ComponentCellView(JComponent component) {
    this.component = component;
  }
  public void update() { component.repaint(); }
  public JComponent getComponent() { return component; }
}
```

Is there any equivalent functionality in android such as .repaint() or ability to call and return a particular view? I have heard a little about invalidate() method that may help in this and also I believe a getView method exists for adapters so maybe this is what I may need to declare for my own custom view. Any thoughts?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have worked very briefly with Swing, but I dont get exactly which equivalent features you are looking for. I'll just confirm about a few you have mentioned.

- invalidate() works and it will call the onDraw() method of the view again.
- Adapters do have getView() method that you can request.
- A custom view example would be like this -

  ```
  View myview = new View (MyActivity.this) {

      @Override
      protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          super.onDraw(canvas);
      }

  };
  ```